# Why aliexpress is advertising my website and referring?

Tags: google-analytics, spam-prevention, referrer-spam

We are running a website(due to security reason cannot disclose the name until we find this solution) and we keep on getting referral link on our analytic account(see image) why would aliexpress and other sites would ask visitors to visit our website, is our application compromised so they are using our website? or this is Chinese being Chinese

[image: 2,3,4,5 are okay but 1 and 6, that's sounds like a big joke to me]

Answer (score 3):

This is clearly referrer spam and doesn't correspond to any traffic to your Web site. The spammers basically send fake pageviews directly to Google Analytics (using randomly chosen property IDs) and their aim is to trick you into following the referrer URLs. Some time ago I wrote an article that explains this in depth and that discusses different approaches to eliminate that referrer spam from Google Analytics:

http://veithen.github.io/2015/01/21/referrer-spam.html